# Getting parseerror in ajax call after deploying to server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I have created an ASP.Net website everything is working fine on the local machine. I deployed it to the staging server and there as well everything was working but now when I am trying to deploy it to the production server now the ajax call which I am making is giving a parse error.

To resolve this and after referring to several post on stack overflow and other websites

- I removed the dataType from the ajax call
- I removed the content type from the ajax call
- I changed the datatype to html
- I did json.stringify to parse the data
- When I am changing the dataType to html it doesn't give me an error but in response i get the entire page's html

But all the above doesnt work. Here is my code

```
function GetRoomTypesPackage(location, arrival, departure, packageId, noofpackage) {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "Index.aspx/GetRoomTypesPackage",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: '{location:"' + location + '",arrival:"' + arrival + '",departure:"' + departure + '",offer:"' + document.getElementById("<%=hdnOffer.ClientID%>").value + '" ,packageId:"' + packageId + '",noofpackage:"' + noofpackage + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; chafrset=ut-8"
        });

        request.done(function (msg) {

            if (msg.d == "No rooms available.") {
                alert(msg.d + "Please select a different date to continue booking.");
                window.location.href = "home.aspx";
            }
});

       request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
        });
```

Comment: I would definitely change dataType back to json.  But other than that, I don't see why it doesn't work.

Comment: Initially the dataType was json but on some post there were asking to change it so i changed but that also didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have configured your handler mappings correctly. Please refer below link on how to configure [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763183(v=vs.100).ASPX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763183%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX)

In essence, This link describes how to set the configuration that enables ASP.NET AJAX-enabled client applications to call ASP.NET Web services (.asmx files). Tasks described in this topic include the following:
Configuring Web services to enable calls from client script.
Configuring JSON serialization.
Configuring the authentication service.
Configuring the role service.
Configuring the profile service.

Hope that helps.